# Stars and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, image-processing

Ok So I have been dying in interviews lately. Need to Brush up more. 
Maybe you can help me with this interview question (multiple Choice). If you tell me good sources to look at to learn more about these algos that would be great.

Heres the Q:

You want to create an algorithm that finds the stars that form Greek Constellations as seen from earth. Which of the following are appropriate algorithms.

a) K means with euclidean distance

b) K nearest Neighbors with cosine similarity

c) K means with Cosine Similarity

d) K Medoids

e) None are correct, i would do something else.

I know that Kmeans is clustering, and KNN is a classification. I also know that the cosine similarity shows how similar 2 vectors are by leveraging the dot product of the 2 vectors (a.b=|a||b|cos(theta)).

Suggestions and help would be great.

Comment: This is essentially a self-study question. Please see the discussion about homework and similar questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - basically, we strongly prefer people to show their existing work on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, there may be no right answer to this question, they may just be looking for you to make some sensible defense of a method. Last, the question might be garbage: it presumes familiarity with all the methods, but a good data scientist/statistician could probably become reasonably familiar with them. And the constellations themselves were identified based on clusters of stars, **but also on fitting patterns to mythological figures**. I don't think you can get these techniques to incorporate that easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question does not make sense. Run from that company, they don't know what they are doing...

They likely expect to hear c), but the correct answer is:

z) None. An algorithm cannot do this. Greek constellations are a (pretty random and stupid) human concept, not a statistical pattern.

[image: XKCD]

Comment: I dunno if they are stupid! I was enthralled by them as a kid, which got me into astronomy, and then science!